# Trouble reproducing ridgeline plot in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I'm trying to reproduce a d3 density ridge plot in javascript but with a different dataset. The code I am modifying comes from the d3 library's documentation and can be seen here: [d3 density ridge example](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/ridgeline_basic.html).

The plot from the code I am modifying  looks like this:
[image]

I took a look at the data in this example. It is an array of objects:

```js
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zonination/perceptions/master/probly.csv", 
    function(data) {console.log(data)}
)
[
   {
     "Almost Certainly": "95",
     "Highly Likely": "80",
     "Very Good Chance": "85",
     "Probable": "75",
     "Likely": "66",
     "Probably": "75",
     "We Believe": "66",
     "Better Than Even": "55",
     "About Even": "50",
     "We Doubt": "40",
     "Improbable": "20",
     "Unlikely": "30",
     "Probably Not": "15",
     "Little Chance": "20",
     "Almost No Chance": "5",
     "Highly Unlikely": "25",
     "Chances Are Slight": "25"
   }
...
]
```

So I am trying to swap out the original dataset with my own dataset, a well-known diamond dataset. To reproduce my issue, here is some code that downloads the diamond dataset and transforms it to be in the same form as the dataset above.

```js
let diamondsDataRaw;
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/main/data-raw/diamonds.csv", function(data){
    diamondsDataRaw_ = data
  }
)

// Get unique cuts
var cuts = [...new Set(diamondsDataRaw.map(d => d.cut))];

// map each distinct cut to cut & price
var distinctCutPrice = cuts.map(cut => {
  var cut_data = diamondsDataRaw.filter(d => d.cut === cut) 
  var distinctCutPrice = cut_data.map(i => {return({cut:i.cut, price:i.price})})
  return(distinctCutPrice)
})
// make all same length
var minLen = ss.min(distinctCutPrice.map(i => i.length))
distinctCutPrice_same_length = distinctCutPrice.map(i => i.slice(0, minLen))
// convert to dataframe
var seqMinLen = [...Array(minLen)].map((v, k)=>k)
var df = seqMinLen.map(i => {
  return({
    Ideal: distinctCutPrice_same_length[0][i].price,
    Premium: distinctCutPrice_same_length[1][i].price,
    Good: distinctCutPrice_same_length[2][i].price,
    "Very Good": distinctCutPrice_same_length[3][i].price,
    Fair: distinctCutPrice_same_length[4][i].price
  })
})
```

Now I try to use their code but swap in my dataset:

```html
<div id = "plot33"></div>
```

```js
function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
  return function(V) {
    return X.map(function(x) {
      return [x, d3.mean(V, function(v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
    });
  };
}
function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
  return function(v) {
    return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
  };
}


var data = df


// Get the different categories and count them
var categories = cuts
var n = categories.length

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 60, right: 30, bottom: 20, left:110},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#plot33")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform",
  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
);


// Add X axis
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-10, 140])
  .range([ 0, width ]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Create a Y scale for densities
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 0.4])
  .range([ height, 0]);

// Create the Y axis for names
var yName = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(categories)
  .range([0, height])
  .paddingInner(1)
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yName));

// Compute kernel density estimation for each column:
var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(40)) // increase this 40 for more accurate density.
var allDensity = []
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var key = categories[i];
  var density = kde(data.map(function(d) { return parseFloat(d[key]); }));
  allDensity.push({key: key, density: density});
}


// Add areas
svg.selectAll("areas")
.data(allDensity)
.enter()
.append("path")
.attr("transform", function(d){return("translate(0," + (yName(d.key)-height) +")" )})
.datum(function(d){return(d.density)})
.attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
.attr("stroke", "#000")
.attr("stroke-width", 1)
.attr("d",  d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
)
```

And this is the result, an empty plot:
[image: Resulting plot]

Any help would be appreciated. My ultimate goal is to try and make something like this:

[image: https://urbaninstitute.github.io/r-at-urban/graphics-guide/www/images/ridgeline-plots-1.png]

Answer (score 1):

A few issues in your code:

1 - you are attempting to use `diamondsDataRaw` outside of the **async** callback in `d3.csv`.

2 - I am not following your data manipulation and couldn't really get past the `ss.min` part (it's undefined).  So I rewrote it simpler (but I'm not sure it is what you are after).

3 - The example you are following uses some hard-coded magic numbers when creating its scales.  These won't work for your different data-set.

Putting this together, here's a somewhat working code sample.  It definitely needs further refinement because as a data visualiztion it makes little sense.  From the data it looks like cut is only one driver of price.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>
var margin = {top: 60, right: 30, bottom: 20, left:110},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/main/data-raw/diamonds.csv", function(data) {

    // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data.map(d => +d.price))])
    .range([ 0, width ]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  var categories = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.cut))];

  var spacing = height / categories.length;

  var kde = kernelDensityEstimator(kernelEpanechnikov(7), x.ticks(40)) 

  var allDensity = [];
  var yMax = 0;
  categories.forEach( c => { 
    let density = kde( 
      data.filter(d => d.cut == c).map(d => +d.price)
    );
    let m = d3.max(density.map( d => d[1]) );
    if (m > yMax) yMax = m;
    allDensity.push({key: c, density: density});
  });

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, yMax])
      .range([spacing, 0]);

  var yName = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(categories)
    .range([0, height])
    .paddingInner(1)
    
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yName));

  svg.selectAll("areas")
    .data(allDensity)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("transform", d => "translate(0," + (yName(d.key) - spacing) +")" )
      .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
      .attr("stroke", "#000")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d",  d => {
        let p = d3.line()
            .curve(d3.curveBasis)
            .x(d => x(d[0]))
            .y(d => y(d[1]))(d.density);
        return p;
      });
});

// This is what I need to compute kernel density estimation
function kernelDensityEstimator(kernel, X) {
  return function(V) {
    return X.map(function(x) {
      return [x, d3.mean(V, function(v) { return kernel(x - v); })];
    });
  };
}
function kernelEpanechnikov(k) {
  return function(v) {
    return Math.abs(v /= k) <= 1 ? 0.75 * (1 - v * v) / k : 0;
  };
}
</script>
```